# Setting dataflow job dependencies using Cloud function and App engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Just a thought, My first job will be triggered by a Cloud Function by any file arrival event. I will capture it's job ID in Cloud Function itself. Once I get the job ID, I will pass that ID to App engine code and that code will monitor the completion of job with that particular ID. Once the App engine code identifies the 'success' status of that job then it will trigger another job which was dependant on the successful completion status for prior job.

Any idea whether it can be made possible or not? If yes, then any help with code samples will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can use PubSub for communication and triggering purposes.

Comment: Ok. so let's consider my scenario. How do I know whether my first job is completed or not before triggering and starting a new job? Say my second job should start only after my first job completes a BigQuery write operation. Any insights?

Comment: Maybe have a look at AirFlow. It might be able to do this for you already. http://airflow.apache.org/